# Omnet++ Send wireless message to limited distance

Tags: omnet++, inet

I develop simulator of mobile nodes, each one with transmission range of 100m for example. The communication between the nodes are wireless and TDMA based.
I have notice that if 2 nodes (not in the same range) broadcast message on the same time, it's cause to a problem.

How can i limit the distance of nessage that is sent from a node ? such that i can broadcast 2 or more messages on the same time, and just the nodes in the range of the sending node will hear the message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that processes the reception of the packet should calculate the distance from the sender and drop the packet if it's out of range.

A little less accurate solution: before sending the packets the broadcasting node should check the distance to the potential receiving node and not send the packet if it is out of range. This is a bit faster (as it generates less packets) and more clear (you will see the broadcast animation only for the packets that actually delivered)

A much easier solution: Use INET Framework, which already has the necessary implementation. You would only need to implement a MAC module that handles the TDMA protocol.